# TCL Get the value of a second level variable

Tags: tcl

I à stuck with a TCL issue. I would like to have access to the content of a second level variable with keeping the format (list).
please see my code :
At first, I declare variable contents

```
set x1y {1 2 3 4}
set x2y {10 11 12 13}
```

After I perform a for loop

```
for { i 0} {i < 4} { incr i}
```

I would like to have in `xy` variable the content of `x1y` with keeping the list format

```
 set xy [eval ["x${i}y"]]
 foreach x $xy {
  ....
 }
```

Do you have any idea / proposal. I tried subst but it doesn’t keep the format.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to read from a variable whose name is not a constant is to use the single argument form of set:

```
set x1y {1 2 3 4}
set x2y {10 11 12 13}

foreach i {1 2} {
    foreach val [set x${i}y] {
        puts "$i --> $val"
    }
}
```

However, it is usually easier to make an alias to the variable with `upvar 0`, like this:

```
foreach i {1 2} {
    upvar 0 x${i}y xy
    foreach val $xy {
        puts "$i --> $val"
    }
}
```

And in almost every case where you're doing this, you should consider using arrays instead (remembering that Tcl's arrays are *associative* arrays; you can use compound keys as well as simple integers):

```
set xy(1) {1 2 3 4}
set xy(2) {10 11 12 13}

foreach i {1 2} {
    foreach val $xy($i) {
        puts "$i --> $val"
    }
}
```

You probably want to try to avoid using `eval` or `subst` for this sort of thing; those commands have side effects that may hurt the stability of your code if you're not careful. Definitely not ones for cases like these. (Also, they'll be slower as they force Tcl to recompile its internal bytecode more frequently. All the solutions I present above don't have that misfeature.)

Answer (score 0):

```
set x1y {1 2 3 4}
set x2y {10 11 12 13}
for {set i 1} {$i <= 2} {incr i} {
     foreach e [set x${i}y] {
            puts $e
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I will add more details. The following code give me the error : "invalid command name 1 2 3 4" at the "foreach surf [eval $List_Surf] {" step

set Raidisseur_1_Surface_Sup {78 79 84 85}
set Raidisseur_2_Surface_Sup {92 93 98 99}
for {set j 1} {$j <= $NB_RAIDISSEURS} {incr j} {
    set Surface_Sup [set Raidisseur_${j}_Surface_Sup]
    set Surface_Liste_WO_LeftRight {$Surface_Sup $Surface_Inf}
    foreach List_Surf $Surface_Liste_WO_LeftRight {
        foreach surf [eval $List_Surf] {
            ...
        }
    }
}